# Calling setEnable within an ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

In a game I am making with buttons, when I click on the "next" button, I would some other buttons to become 'grayed out' so that you cannot click on them. I have this code in my ActionListener for the 'Next' button:

```
    public class NextListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        nextButton.setEnabled(false);
        callButton.setEnabled(false);
        raiseButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

However, when I run the program, the buttons do not gray out, and I get the error:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Have you initialised your references to `nextButton`, `callButton` and `raiseButton`?

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to call methods on null variables, so this suggests that one or all of the JButton variables that you're calling `setEnabled(...)` on are null. Solution: assign valid references to the variables before trying to call methods on them.

This can be done via constructor parameter or some such. Or better yet, give the class that holds those button variables a public method that allows you to change the state of its buttons, and pass a reference of just this object, the container object to the ActionListener.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MyContainer {
   JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
   JButton callButton = new JButton("Call");
   JButton raiseButton = new JButton("Raise");

   private ActionListener nextListener = new NextListener(this);

   public void buttonsSetEnabled(boolean enabled) {
      nextButton.setEnabled(enabled);
      callButton.setEnabled(enabled);
      raiseButton.setEnabled(enabled);
   } 
}
```

elsewhere

```
public class NextListener implements ActionListener {
   private MyContainer myContainer;

   public NextListener(MyContainer myContainer) {
      this.myContainer = myContainer;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
      myContainer.buttonsSetEnabled(false);
   };
}
```